# How can I access the Internet via a JavaScript program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to code a program in Java Script on Visual Studio that requires the use of the internet to define a variable, but how do I do that?  My program requires the user input to be searched on Google to return certain information.  I'm new to Visual Studio, so I'm not sure where to start.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want in the variable. If you have an API endpoint you can use them fetch function to get data. Though if you do not plan to run the program in the browser you will need to install nose and node-fetch to do that. 
 If you more want to simulate something in the browser based on inputs you'll have to use something like puppeteer.

You'll have to be a little more clear here on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Ajex and Rest Api.

Example:

```html
var key = "abc"; // your api key registered with google.

$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="+key+"q="+query
}).then(
  function(data){
    // read data from here...
  }
)
```

Reference:

[Using REST to Invoke the API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest)

Answer (score -2):

Since you mentioned Google search, there's Google's Angular framework.  There are others, React from Facebook and jQuery.  All these are JavaScript and can be used in Visual Studio.
They have their own approach and learning curve.